# calling multiple array from subroutines

Tags: perl

I am only able to print 1st section when I am calling array from subroutine.
Within subroutine I am able to print all the records but when I call same array on top of the script I am only getting below output.

```
@array = test();
DEBUG(Dumper(\@array);

2014/07/04 1:28:38 $VAR1 = [
          [
            'Router1',
            'Router2',
            'Router3',
          ]
        ];



sub test {      
    my @array;    
    for my $record (@array) {
        for my $value (@$record) {
            DEBUG("DEBUG: Value of array $value ");
        }
    }
    return (@array);
}
```

Dumper output is like below:

```
2014/07/04 1:28:38 $VAR1 = [
          [
            'Router1',
            'Router2',
            'Router3',
          ]
        ];
2014/07/04 1:28:38 $VAR1 = [
          [
            'Switch1',
            'Switch2',
            'Switch3',
          ]
        ];

2014/07/04 1:28:38 $VAR1 = [
          [
            'Switch11',
            'Switch21',
            'Switch31',
          ]
        ];
```

Expected output:

```
Router1
Router2
Router3
Switch1
Switch2
Switch3
Switch11
Switch21
Switch31
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not working for me ..Any other way ...$array = &test();DEBUG(Dumper($array));

Comment: I am getting $VAR1 = undef;

Comment: I have changes return value from @array to \@array;  but still I am getting only the 1st set as before .

Comment: Anyone please help.....

Comment: The code you show will not compile. I presume you actually have `DEBUG(Dumper(\@array));`?

Comment: How about adding everything, so we can help you?

Comment: Thanks for the response !! This is all I have now. I have provided the dumper's output of array. But it's printing only 1st section of loop...$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Router1',
            'Router2',
            'Router3',
          ]
        ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subroutine `test` declares an empty array `@array` and dumps it. You will get no output because it is empty. The array you are dumping at the start of the program is a different array

Comment: Thanks for the response . Yeah I have removed my @array from subroutine that and I am still getting the only the 1st part of output. I don't know why it's not printing all the values ...

Comment: Please show your *complete* code. You have left out the part that is causing the problem